# Passing variables with continuous functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using a function to read an analog value from a joystick and update the label on the tkinter screen. This works well but I also want to use that value outside the function to perform if statements with other returned values. Here is what I have so far:

```
def joystick():
    global joystick_adc
    joystickRead = readadc(joystick_adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
    joystickValue = joystickRead
    joy_val.config(text=joystickRead)
    joy_val.after(1000, joystick)
    return joystickValue
```

After it is returned I am assigning it to a variable using:

```
joystickVal = joystick()
```

But it only returns the value once and not continuously like I had hoped. Is there something I am doing wrong here??

Comment: Can you elaborate on *But it only returns the value once*? How figured this out?

Comment: How about defining `joystickValue` globally?

Comment: I mean the value updates on the tkinter label every second but the joystickVal value is only returned once and never again. So the label is updating with the correct value but the variable "joystickVal" is not.

Comment: @Jamessin There are two possibilities, 1. Your function executes only one time, 2. It doesn't reach to the return line at hence the next calls. Which if  the value updates on the tkinter label every second the second option might be true. Is this like so? does your function return any exception before return?

Comment: @NullUserException Right now the 'joy_val.after(1000, joystick)' line is calling it every second, with the 1000 being in ms, so i figured if it was being called every second then it would return the value for joystickVal every second also but it does not seem to be doing that.

Comment: @Jamessin `.after` registers `joystick()` as a callback with tkinter. So yes, the function itself will be called every second by tkinter. But whatever else you have calling the same function will not magically get its return value.

Comment: Your function is being called by the tkinter event loop. It returns to the event loop which ignores the value. You could save the result in a global value.

Comment: @Kasramvd: _"there are two possibilities..."_ - no, there is a third. The return _is_ being called every time the function is called. The value is being returned to the caller, but except for the first time the caller is `mainloop`,.

Comment: @BryanOakley Indeed, good catch!

Comment: So could I put a while loop in the joystick function that puts the value to a global variable and then have tkinter pull off of that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you *really* need such architecture, you could do it like this:

```
def joystick(adc):
    global joystickVal
    joystickVal = readadc(adc, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
    joy_val.config(text=joystickVal)
    joy_val.after(1000, joystick, adc)

joystick(joystick_adc)  # to start
# Also this wouldn't stop, so you'd better coding it in class with shared
# attribute, used to indicate condition
```

But you'd better avoiding such patterns, cause it brings strong coupling. Generally, function should be as independent, as possible

See how it's properly done in ThreadDispatcher [here](https://gist.github.com/thodnev/d2c70d1034d1b8547fa8edf1c297b859)

**UPD:** (part of reply to your comment)
for simulating readadc:

```
def sim(string):
    parts = string.splitlines()
    def callback(*args, **kwargs):
        if parts:
            cur = parts.pop(0)
            return cur
        return 'Empty'
    return callback

sim_adc = sim('Firs\nsecond\nthird\netc...')  # run func with this
```

Comment: I just tried that and it still does not seem to be updating the value for joystickVal...I'm taking that value and putting it in an if statement outside of the function but it only is updating once so the if statement is not working.

Comment: @Jamessin hmm... if so, it seems that your joystick returns the same. Try simulating readadc with something, which returns parts of strings

Comment: @thodnev is this all in one module? The module-level variable is updated to the same value as the label.

Comment: @tdelaney right, it reflects the last value read from adc. Anyway, that's bad design, I couldn't even imagine when it could be really needed and unavoidable

Comment: @thodnev I don't think it's a particularly bad design. The joystick reader needs to record the value somewhere. You could make it a class and store the value in an instance.... But then that instance would have to be available somewhere. I don't mind globals as long as their use is documented. How would you keep an updated value?

Comment: @tdelaney a decorator-class, which takes polling routine at instantiation time, has overriden `__call__` (doing actual polling) as long as `property` read-only descriptor for viewing the last state (or get method). What I mean is: https://gist.github.com/thodnev/43b238d90a5a8e4b2fe671196d4c79a6

Comment: @tdelaney anyway, using just `after` callbacks isn't enough. Joysticks are fast and tkinter is slow. For proper handling, it's needed to have a separate worker thread, which polls joystick at certain intervals (with `time.sleep` as timer) and posts result on a shared queue. That results are then dispatched on the main (GUI) thread by getting values from the queue with much slower tkinter after callback

Answer (score 1):

By far, the simplest solution is to simply make `joystickValue` a global variable.

```
def joystick():
    global joystickValue
    ...
    joystickValue = joystickRead
    ...
```

Generally speaking, global variables should be avoided. In an event driven program, however, they are a necessity. It would be better to use classes for your application, but it appears that you're not so globals in this case are unavoidable.

---

In your code, it actually *is* returning the value every time it's called. It's just that it's returning the value to `mainloop` rather than whatever function called it the first time.  That is because you use `after` which defers the call to a future date. The code that makes that call in the future is not your code, but rather `mainloop`.

Comment: I would add a while True: loop in my joystick function and have that put the value to a global variable but then the application does not start it just updates the value..

Comment: @Jamessin: why would you put a `while True` statement in a GUI? That's just an infinite loop, and you already have an infinite loop running (`mainloop()`)

Comment: because i'm just trying to somehow get a value from the joystick function that I can use for If statements and controlling GPIO pins. I can't use joy_val because its a StringVar(). Like i said i'm new to this so i am just trying anything that might work.

Comment: @Jamessin: try the code in this answer. It calls your joystick function once a second and stores the value in a variable. You can then use that variable anywhere in your code.

Comment: I did try that and if i create the global variable joystickValue in the joystick function then try and use that it says it is not defined. I am trying to use it in as 'if (joystickValue > 1000): GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)' but it always says joystickValue is not defined in the if statement...